# Can someone explaing to me how and where to use mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I have a database dump(bson and json files). I have Mongo set up and working. I can even access the empty db from my rest API server but I can't figure out where I can use the mongorestore command. I tried it in the shell and I get a syntax error

```
mongorestore -d forum D:\forum
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:16
```

Anywhere else I get this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)>mongorestore -d forum D:\forum
'mongorestore' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So how do I use it? Apparently, the 2nd one should be working but it's not for me.

Comment: Change to the folder where Mongo restore is saved

Comment: To where? I have tried to move it to different folders in D but still, the same I even tried to put it in the data/db/forum folder.

Comment: Rather than change to the folder where mongorestore is located, instead add the path to mongorestore to the system `PATH` variable.  This way you can call the program from anywhere without a need to fully qualify the path to the program.